# How to print some values only once from array

Tags: arrays, f#

i have mixes strings and arrays in a function to print out a csv  file.
Some of the cell though should be filled only once, but I cannot really figure out how to.
this is that I have.

```
    let handle = "handle1"
    let title  = "title1"
   
    let stringedBody = "Impusm Body"
    
    let data = Array.zip3 variantPrice variantComparePrice storlek
    let lines = data |> Array.map (fun (vp, vcp, size) ->
                     sprintf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" handle title vp vcp size stringedBody)
                
    
     let header = "handle\ttitle\tvariantPrice\tvariantComparePrice\tstorlek\tbody"
            
    
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("\\UITest\\UITest\\data\\test.csv", 
                    Array.append [| header|]lines, Encoding.UTF8)
```

prints out

```
handle  title   variantPrice    variantComparePrice storlek body
handle1 title1       XX                 xx              xx  Ipsum Body
handle1 title1       XX                 xx              xx  Ipsum Body
handle1 title1       XX                 xx              xx  Ipsum Body
handle1 title1       XX                 xx              xx  Ipsum Body
```

Ideal would be that only the ones in the array repeats but the other ones only once

```
handle  title   variantPrice    variantComparePrice storlek body
handle1 title1       XX                 xx              xx  Ipsum Body
handle1              XX                 xx              xx  
handle1              XX                 xx              xx  
handle1              XX                 xx              xx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is print the first line separately, and then print the remaining lines with empty cells.

There are a variety of ways to do this, but the shortest one in my opinion would be to use `Array.mapi` instead of `Array.map`. `Array.mapi` provides each element's index in addition to the element itself, so that you can use the index to determine if the line is the first one or not:

```
let lines = 
    data 
    |> Array.mapi (fun idx (vp, vcp, size) ->
        let printTitle = if idx = 0 then title else ""
        let printBody = if idx = 0 then stringedBody else ""
        sprintf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" handle printTitle vp vcp size printBody
    )
```